# concat by taking the values from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a list ['df1', 'df2'] where i have stores some dataframes which have been filtered on few conditions. Then i have converted this list to dataframe using
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
now the df has only one column

0

df1

df2

sometimes it may also have

0

df1

df2

df3

i wanted to concate all these my static code is

df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1) or

df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)

how can i make it dynamic (without me specifying as df1,df2) so that it takes the values and concat it.

Comment: Post some input data and expected output

Comment: as i have posted above i have those columns i wanted to write something so that pd.concat([......]) has taken all the values in the column

Comment: you can add the list of data frames to an array, did you try that?

Comment: no i dint try that

Comment: @guruR, check my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using array to add the lists and data frames :

```
import pandas as pd

lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
arr = []
for l in lists:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(l)
    arr.append(new_df)

df = pd.concat(arr,axis=1)
df
```

Result :

```
    0   0
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

Comment: my list is this ['df1', 'df2'], when i apply to this it gives DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: @guruR, plz edit your question and add your list. I am not sure I understand why you have df1 and df1 between single quotations? I mean, add your code after you took mine, so I can see whats wrong